# "Der Tisch ist rund", can it be rephrased with both "Er ist rund" and "Es ist rund"?

Tags: article

I understand that Tisch is a masculine noun, and according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQIUBsvakyc&list=PL5QyCnFPRx0GxaFjdAVkx7K9TfEklY4sg&index=10) video, to refer to it I should use "Er". But a table is an object. Is it wrong to say "Es ist rund" when referring to a table? (Why?) Are both "Er" and "Es" OK? Is there a sort-of general rule for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pronouns are gendered based on grammatical gender, so even though it is an inanimate object, you still use 'er' because it is masculine.

The only time you would go against this rule is to refer to people by their biological gender even if they are a 'Mädchen' for example, but even that is not always the case.

With inanimate objects (or with anything else really - that is what is strictly correct and what natives usually do), use grammatical gender, so:

> er ist rund

Comment: Ahhh, "Es" is for neutral gender! I had incorrectly assumed that is was equivalent to "it" in English. Danke!

Comment: Lebendig oder tot ist kein Kriterium. Grammatisches Geschlecht hängt eben nicht vom biologischen Geschlecht ab (siehe auch die Taube).

Comment: From my experience with humans people will sometimes in informal contexts use biological gender, but you're right it's not strictly correct and less common than using grammatical gender.

Comment: "Das Mädchen griff zur Suppe. Sie kochte." vs. "Das Mädchen griff zur Suppe. Es kochte." Es gibt in der Sprache m.W. keine Regel, die eine Unterscheidung zw. belebten und unbelebten Größen macht, außer in der Semantik selbst, also dass ein Metalltisch nicht essen kann, zum Beispiel.